# add members button javascript

Tags: javascript, button

как добавить такой функционал в форму?
нужно добавить form -group и возможность удалить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<section class="regSection ">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="row  full-row">

      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>

          <!-- Form Name -->
          <legend class="nonBorder">Your family members details</legend>

          <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="radios">Salutation</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label class="radio-inline" for="radios-0">
                <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-0" value="Mr." checked="checked">Mr.
              </label>
              <label class="radio-inline" for="radios-1">
                <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-1" value="Ms.">Ms.
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <input id="firstName" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder=" " class="form-control input-md" required="">
              <span class="help-block"> </span> 
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <input id="lastName" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder=" " class="form-control input-md">
              <span class="help-block"> </span> 
            </div>
          </div>


          <!-- Select Basic -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="relation">Relationship:</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <select id="relation" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">Select</option>
                <option value="2">Op1</option>
                <option value="">Op2</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>




          <div class="hr  smallWeight">
          </div>
          <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
          "hr smallWeight"></div>
    <div class="addButton">
      <button type="button" class="btn  add"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Family Member</button>


    </div>

    </fieldset>
    </form>

</section>
```

Comment: ну надо... добавляйте... Вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: очень остроумно))
первое предложение с вопросом стёрлось

Comment: Можно, например, руками добавить. Или вы хотите, чтобы мы все сделали за вас?

Comment: мне просто помощь нужна в написании такого скрипта или подсказка

Comment: Подсказываю: используйте JavaScript. А если серьезно, то если вам нужна помощь, а не готовый код, задавайте конкретные вопросы: что именно вы делали, что не получилось. Если же вам все-таки нужен готовый код -- вам прямая дорога на биржу фрилансеров. Там все сделают за вас и в лучшем виде. Правда не бесплатно

Comment: @DmitriySimushev прав - хотя бы покажите, что Вы хоть что-то пытались сделать... Если не пытались - то смотрите в сторону jQuery метода `clone()`. Хотя может быть и ругие варианты... Это максимум, что мы можем Вам посоветовать на данный момент...

Comment: в том то и дело, что ничего не получаетса
я только начала учить    javascript

Comment: cyadvert spasibo

Comment: Я уже отвечал на такой вопрос, но не могу найти...

Comment: @Qwertiy  попробую пойскать
спасибо

Comment: "_ничего не получаетса я только начала учить javascript_" значит пути у вас всего три: учите JS и задавайте конкретные вопросы, отправляйтесь на биржу фрилансеров и платите за решение или ждите, пока кто-то, кто поощряет человеческую лень решит дать ответ на ваш вопрос. Как-то так.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev я заинтригован: а третий путь? ;)

Comment: @cyadvert, так я же три указал: учить, платить, ждать)))

Comment: @DmitriySimushev можно было просто как  cyadvert ответить где искать
почему сразу злиться&

Comment: @Marusya, моя, как вы говорите "злость" сподвигла вас на самостоятельный поиск решения. А тот факт, что вы его нашли, я могу смело считать педагогическим успехом ;)

Comment: @Marusya поверьте, это он не злится... Это, как настоящий программер, он перечисляет возможные варианты :)

Comment: @cyadvert всё равно спасибо вам

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("form").clone().appendTo("section ");
        });
    });
</script>
```

вот что получилось))

Comment: и как? работает?

Comment: добавляет не туда пока)))

Comment: Обратите внимание, что таким способом Вы клонируете ВСЮ форму. Т.е. у вас на странице будет 2, 3, 4 и т.д. разных форм.... а не одна большая...

Comment: да
тестирую))  нужно с классами разобраться

Comment: а  delete  это какой метод?т.е удалить form-group

Comment: Ну мне что, английские синонимы delete перечислять? Могли бы и сами найти... Вам, скорее всего, нужен `remove()`

Comment: спасибо 
все получилось